# Can't connect to my kernel in jupyter-lab on GitHub Codespaces

Tags: github, jupyter-lab, github-codespaces, jupyter-kernel

I am setting up GitHub Codespaces for my project.

I have my `.devcontainer` configuration with a following Dockerfile:

```
FROM condaforge/mambaforge:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install sudo gcc --yes && apt-get clean
RUN mamba install -c conda-forge \
  "conda-build == 3.25.0" "boa == 0.15.1" "conda-verify == 3.1.1" "jupyter-lab"
```

Relevant section of the `.decontainer.json`:

```
    "build": { "dockerfile": "Dockerfile" },

    "privileged": true,

    "forwardPorts": [8000, 9000],

    "portsAttributes": {
        "8000": {
            "label": "HTTP",
            "protocol": "http",
            "onAutoForward": "notify",
            "elevateIfNeeded": true
        },
        "9000": {
            "label": "HTTPS",
            "protocol": "https",
            "onAutoForward": "notify",
            "elevateIfNeeded": true
        }
    },
```

I start the codespace and then in the terminal I run `jupyter-lab --port 8000 --allow-root` and the server starts; I open it it another browser tab, paste the authentication token and Jupyter Lab initiates. However, whenever I try to work in a notebook I am stuck on "Connecting to the IPython kernel" stage. Do I need to specify some more options for the codespace? Or maybe for the Jupyter server?

Answer (score 0):

Try `conda install nb_conda_kernels`. This should make any conda envs visible as eligible notebook kernels.